# add rows with loop max value +1

Tags: php, mysql, loops, max

I'm trying to add rows to the database based on the input value. 
i.e. If input as "5", query will insert 5 rows to database. (this part is working fine)

Now, I need the bed_number to be +1 to the existing max(bed_number) but i can't seems to get it to work.

If existing max(bed_number) returns 5, than the query should add "6,7,8,9,10, etc" as the bed_number for the 5 entries.

If existing max(bed_number) returns null, than it should add "1,2,3,4,5, etc"

Right now, the result always return 1,2,3,4,5... regardless of the max count.

What i have here now is:

```
global $conn;
if ($values["number_of_bed"])
{

$add1 = $values["number_of_bed"]+1;
$existingBed = "select Max(bed_number) from bed where bed =" '".$i."'" +1;

for ($i=1;$i<$add1;$i++)
{
 $strInsert = "insert into bed (unit_id,bed_number) values ('".$values["unit_id"]."','".$existingBed."')";


 db_exec($strInsert,$conn);
}
header("Location: bed_list.php");

 // Exit and Redirect to the list page after updating database
exit();
```

Comment: sorry, this is php 5.3.13 / mysql 5.5.24

Comment: is that really the code? because, it looks like syntax error to me.

Comment: You need to do the +1 on the `MAX()` -> `SELECT MAX(bed_number)+1 FROM bed WHERE bed = $i`

Comment: also, when doing a `SELECT` in the `VALUES`, you don't use `VALUES` and wrap in parentheses `()`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html It should look more like `INSERT INTO bed (unit_id, bed_number) SELECT '$values["unit_id"]', MAX(bed_number)+1 FROM bed WHERE bed = $1`

Comment: Why not make `bed_number` auto increment then you don't have to worry about it?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the bed_number is assigned to each bed. within the same table, each entry is assigned with bed_id which is auto_increment.

Comment: managed to get the result i wanted by this:

Answer (score 0):

```
//echo "Number of customers: " . $data["c"];

global $conn;
if ($values["bed_number"])
{

$add1 = $values["bed_number"]+1;


//for ($i=1;$i<$values["bed_number"];$i++)
for ($i=1;$i<$add1;$i++)
{
$sql = "select max(bed_number) as c from bed where unit_id =" . $values["unit_id"];
$rs = CustomQuery($sql);
$data = db_fetch_array($rs);
$strInsert = "insert into bed (unit_id,bed_number) values ('".$values["unit_id"]."','".$data["c"]."'+1)";
 // add more fields from the add page to be inserted into database

 db_exec($strInsert,$conn);
}
header("Location: bed_list.php");

 // Exit and Redirect to the list page after updating database
exit();

}
```